# how to open a music app in android 5 from code

Tags: android

how to open a music app in android 5 from code which starts playing the first song by default without giving any specific query, i tired "android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" , but it shows error as to there is no default application to handle this intent, please help !

Comment: do you want to open your own song or music app?

Comment: The music app and it must start playing any song by !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it

```
 ` Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS,"vnd.android.cursor.item/*");
                 startActivity(intent);`
```

the above works

Answer (score 0):

According to the developer docs

"INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER"

This constant was deprecated in API level 15.
Use CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC instead.

Activity Action: Launch a music player. The activity should be able to play, browse, or manipulate music files stored on the device.

Constant Value: "android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"

So you have to use another activity which can play musci like native app.

another solution is reflection API.
in your onClick listener write below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

```
try {
     String pkgname = "com.sec.android.app.music";
     PackageManager pkgmanager = getPackageManager();
     Intent intent = pkgmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
     startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```